# On the positive definiteness of the observability Gramian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, positive-definite, linear-control

Given the system $\dot{x} = Ax$, $y = Cx$, it is known that the Gramian, given by

$$ W({t_0},{t_1}) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} e^{A^T(\tau -t_0)}C^TC e^{A(\tau -t_0)} \,{\rm d}\tau $$

is positive definite for some $t_1 > t_0$ if the system is observable. Assuming I know that the system is observable and hence $W \succ 0$, is it possible to show that $e^{A^T(t_1 -t_0)}C^TC e^{A(t_1 -t_0)} \succ 0$?

I found the following lemma[[2]](http://tsakalis.faculty.asu.edu/notes/sco.pdf)

---

[image]

---

However, $$e^{A^T(t_1 -t_0)}C^TC e^{A(t_1 -t_0)} \succ 0$$ does not seem to directly follow from this. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, $p\le n$. If $p<n$, then the matrix

$$\Psi:=e^{A^T(t_1 -t_0)}C^TC e^{A(t_1 -t_0)}$$

is only positive semidefinite for all $t_1,t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ unless $p=n$ and $C$ is full rank.

First note that

$$u^T\Psi u=v^Tv=||v||_2^2$$

where $v=C e^{A(t_1 -t_0)}u$. Then, we have that the matrix $\Psi$ is positive semidefinite.

If it is positive definite, then $u^T\Psi u=0$ should imply that $u=0$. However, let $N$ be a basis for the null-space of $C$. Then, we have that

$$\Psi e^{-A(t_1 -t_0)}Nv=e^{A^T(t_1 -t_0)}C^TCNv=0$$

for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. As a result, we have that

$$v^TN^Te^{-A^T(t_1 -t_0)}\Psi e^{-A(t_1 -t_0)}Nv=0$$

where $e^{-A(t_1 -t_0)}Nv\ne0$. Therefore, the matrix can only be positive definite if $C$ has no null-space (i.e. $C$ is square and full-rank).

---

In any way, it is the integral of that which is positive definite as the sum of positive semidefinite matrices can be positive definite. For instance, the sum of the matrices $$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\ \mathrm{and}\ M_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

is obviously positive definite. This means that one cannot infer the positive definiteness of matrices involved in a sum that is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.